# Need some help about foreign keys and select

Tags: mysql

I have 2 talbes as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE topics (
   topic_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   topic_category INT(11) NOT NULL,
   topic_title VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
   topic_content TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE categories(
   category_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   category_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

Then, i used a foreign key so i can link the topic_category with a category from the 'categories' table.

```
ALTER TABLE topics ADD FOREIGN KEY(topic_category) REFERENCES categories(category_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

My question is, how can i select all the topics with a caetgory of my choosing? I have try the code below and it works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_category = 2
```

Is there a way to make my selection based on the category_name instead of the category_id using something like this? (I know its totally wrong):

```
SELECT * FROM topics WHERE category_name = 'Technology' ;
```

Comment: That is the most simple join. You should take a SQL tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM topics t
INNER JOIN categories c
   ON t.topic_category=c.category_id
WHERE category_name = 'Technology' ;
```

Comment: It works fine. I am trying to implement this in a php script but i dont get any rows back even thought i should. Am i doing something wrong? Sorry but I'm new to php/Mysql, my code is below: 
    $check=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `topics` t INNER JOIN `categories` c ON t.topic_category=c.category_id WHERE `category_name` = 'Technology' ORDER BY topic_date DESC");
    if(mysql_num_rows($check)!=0)
 {
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($check))
  {
   //blahblahblah
  }
 }

Comment: Just post a new question. I guess my answer is right now.